# Регулярное выражение для извлечения id из ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, функции, selenium, test-automation

Пишу Selenium тест в котором пользователь создаёт несколько продуктов и потом по очереди их открывает. При создании продукты получают `Id` по схеме `#product-номер`. В методе я получаю ссылку и подставляю её в регулярное выражение для получения массива из ссылки и id. Дальше уже подставляю iClickOnElement('#product-'.$id[1]);.

```
$productUrl = 'category/category-product/product/!422';
preg_match('#^.*?!([^!]+)$#', $productUrl, $id);
var_dump($id);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
    string(38) "category/category-product/product/!422"
  [1]=>
    string(3) "422"
}
```

Вопрос какие ещё могут быть варианты получения id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не согласен с предыдущим ответом. Регулярные выражения - это механизм упрощающий работу со строками (в обмен на быстродействие). Скорее правильнее было-бы сказать, что тут можно обойтись регулярными выражениями, а не использовать сложные алгоритмы со строковыми функциями. Как пример эквивалент предыдущему ответу:

```
preg_match('/!(.*)$/', $productUrl, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Но наверно правильнее бы было бы написать так:

```
preg_match('/!([^!]+)$/', $productUrl, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Если же `Id` числовой то можно так:

```
preg_match('/!(\d+)$/', $productUrl, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Вопрос был "какие ещё могут быть варианты". И кстати, извлечение подстроки не может быть "сложным алгоритмом" по определению.

Comment: А я и не говорил, что вы не правы. Я сказал, что я не согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам нужно лишь Id, которое идёт после восклицательного знака, то для этого можно не использовать регулярные выражения:

```
var_dump(substr($productUrl, strrpos($productUrl, '!') + 1));
```